# Chose between multiple record in same column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column which might have multiple records for a same item and sometimes it may not.

```
Item       Date          quantity
1          Default        10
2          Default        10
2          27-Nov-2015    30
```

I need to pick up exact record when date matches the criteria. If current date matches for Item 2, then i need to pick quantity as 30 else i need pick the default value. for Item 1, since there is no specific date, i always need to pick quantity 10.

Help required in writing this in Oracle query.

Comment: where is criteria coming from?

Comment: criteria is current date (just plain sys date). if current date is same as specific date on the column, pick the quantity else pick the quantity of default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this with UNION ALL. One part to get the current date record, one part to get the default record in case no current date record exists. In spite of using UNION ALL you would always get one record, one or the other:

```
select * 
from mytable
where item = :item
and date = to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
union all
select * 
from mytable
where item = :item
and date = 'Default'
and not exists
(
  select * 
  from mytable
  where item = :item
  and date = to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
);
```

The alternative is to rank your records with ROW_NUMBER, such as to give the better record row number #1 and keep this:

```
select item, date, quantity
from
(
  select 
    mytable.*,
    row_number() over (order by case when date = 'Default' then 2 else 1 end) rn
  from mytable
  where item = :item
  and date in  (to_char(sysdate,'dd-mmm-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'), 'Default')
)
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this type of prioritization is to use `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where date = '27-Nov-2015'
union all
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.item = t.item and t2.date = '27-Nov-2015'
                 ) and
      t2.date = 'Default';
```

If you only want the result for one item, I prefer this method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from table t
      where item = :v_item
      order by (case when date = 'Default' then 1 else 2 end) desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```